# Permanent Change of Array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I have an array in C++, and I want the user to be able to change the values in the array in cmd permanently even when he closes the console...

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;
int array[3];
int change; 
int main () {
   array[0] = 1;
   array[1] = 2;
   array[2] = 3;

   cout << "Change the second value of array (array[1])" << endl;
   cin >> change;
   array[1] = change;
}
```

The code above is just change the `array[1]`'s value for temporary..
Please help me..

Thank You, Beginner Programmer

Comment: Store the data in a file, read it in at the start and then write back to the file at the end with any changes.

Comment: What is supposed to happen if the user starts multiple instances of your program at the same time and enters different values?

Comment: Imagine if user change the array[1]'s value to 100, so when the program is closed and restart, the value of array[1] must be 100..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a file to store the array data, like what @NathanOliver said. For example:

```
int arr[3];
ifstream in("data.txt");                                        //Open file for input
in >> arr[0] >> arr[1] >> arr[2];                               //Input all data
cout << "Change the second value of array (array[1])" << '\n';
cin >> arr[1];                                                  //Input change
in.close();                                                     //Close input from file
ofstream out("data.txt");                                       //Output to file
out << arr[0] << ' ' << arr[1] << ' ' << arr[2];
out.close();
```

The file should contain the starting value of `arr`, with a space in between.

Comment: The call to remove is not needed.  Constructing the `ofstream` object truncates the file.

Comment: Can you show me what should the content in data.txt be?

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks for the heads-up

Comment: I have tested it but the value of that array become symbols.. Can you help me??

Comment: Thanks so much, now i can store the data to txt file

Answer (score 0):

Any data you use in a program is stored in memory until you exit your program. After that, all data members are destroyed, and you cannot access them by any means. The only way to access data you used during a previous program 'session' is to store your data in a permanent storage, such as your filesystem.

As to how one would write and read array data from disk, there's plenty of different ways to do this with C++. You can look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16566652/read-write-file-into-array), for example.